# Saving all posts to .NET WebService in XML to DB

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I am sure this is an easy question however I am not finding the solution. I want to save the XML files posted to my .NET Web Service. I am sure it is just a simple method call when the service is invoked but I am not finding it. I would like to save the full XML posted to the service

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: question is far too broad to be answered. Can you be more specific?

Comment: You needed to specify that you were using a legacy ASMX web service, and not a WCF service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your help however I found what I was looking for at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx

To help anyone else that is new to tring to implement this via WebService's I included the steps that I performed to implement it and modifications so I could save it to the db as well as the file system I performed the following steps. If you have any questions please feel free to aks and I will be happy to answer.

1. Created a code file in my web service project with the code listed in the in the article
2. Created a few properties to store values to save to the db

   ```
   private string _requestXml;
   private DateTime _start;
   ```
3. Then I modified the WriteInput method to save values to those variables.

   ```
   public void WriteInput(SoapMessage message)
   {
       //Begin Edit
       oldStream.Position = 0;
       _requestXml = new StreamReader(_oldStream).ReadToEnd();
       _start = DateTime.UtcNow;
       //End Edit
       //Begin Original Code
       oldStream.Position = 0;
       Copy(oldStream, newStream);
       var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
       var w = new StreamWriter(fs);
       var soapString = (message is SoapServerMessage) ? "SoapRequest" : "SoapResponse";
       w.WriteLine("-----" + soapString + " at " + DateTime.Now);
       w.Flush();
       newStream.Position = 0;
       Copy(newStream, fs);
       w.Close();
       newStream.Position = 0;
   }
   ```
4. Then I modified the WriteOutput to

   ```
   public void WriteOutput(SoapMessage message)
   {
       //Begin Edit
       var responseXml = new StreamReader(newStream).ReadToEnd();
       newStream.Position = 0;
       //Start process for saving to DB 
       //"_requestXml" = Original Request Soap Message
       //"responseXml" = Service Returned Response
       //"_start" = Request Start Time
       //message.MethodInfo.Name = I save this so I know what method from     
       //message.Url = I save this so I know the original ASMX that was hit
       //End Edit
       //Begin Original Code
       newStream.Position = 0;
       var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
       var w = new StreamWriter(fs);
       var soapString = (message is SoapServerMessage) ? "SoapResponse" : "SoapRequest";
       w.WriteLine("-----" + soapString + " at " + DateTime.Now);
       w.Flush();
       Copy(newStream, fs);
       w.Close();
       newStream.Position = 0;
       Copy(newStream, oldStream);
   }
   ```
5. Now all that's left is to add the following to your service call and you should be good to go

   ```
   [WebMethod, NameSpace.OfyourTraceExtesionClass.TraceExtension]
   public void WebMethod1()
   {
       //DoSomeStuff
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log the http post messages, an elegant way of solving it would be to set up a simple reverse proxy in front of your web services. In this proxy you would have full access to the raw http request.

Answer (score 0):

- XML file received as Stream
- Convert Stream to byte[]
- Convert byte[] to XDocument (System.Xml.Linq)
- Read XDocument with LINQ syntax and save to DB

Answer (score 0):

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void XMLPersing()
    {
        var XMLDATA = "";

        WriteLogCLS objWriteLog = new WriteLogCLS();
        Stream receiveStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
        receiveStream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);      //For xml persing..
        XMLDATA = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        readStream.Close();

      objWriteLog.WriteLog(Convert.ToString(XMLDATA));
        XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("Log/Exception/Sample.xml"));
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
        xmlreader.Close();
        if (ds.Tables.Count != 0)
        {
            var strCon = string.Empty;
            strCon = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["constring"];
            SqlCommand cmdInsertXMLData = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection SqlConn;
            SqlConn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
            try
            {
                cmdInsertXMLData = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertXML", SqlConn);
                cmdInsertXMLData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                // cmdInsertLoginDetails.Parameters.Add("@XMLdata", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = ds.GetXml();
                cmdInsertXMLData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XMLdata", SqlDbType.Xml);

                if (SqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    SqlConn.Open();
                }
                cmdInsertXMLData.ExecuteNonQuery();
                // response = cmdInsertLoginDetails.Parameters["@Message"].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                objWriteLog.WriteLog("Error on XML Persing : " + ex.Message);
                // response = "Error";
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmdInsertXMLData != null)
                {
                    cmdInsertXMLData.Dispose();
                }
                if (SqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    SqlConn.Close();
                    SqlConn.Dispose();
                }
                objWriteLog = null;
            }
            // return response  ;

        }
    }
}
```